# How to mock the image response in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

#### My problem

I'm trying to simulate a response from the server containing an image with `cy.intercept` however, the browser **won't display** my mocked image. The browser just can't interpret my response as a proper image for `<img>` tag.

[image: debug tools screenshot]

I can still copy the response in debug tools and it seems to be the image I need but probably encoded in the wrong way.

#### My approach

```
    cy.readFile('src/assets/logo.png', 'binary').then((imgContent) => {
      cy.intercept('/uploads/test.png', {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' },
        body: imgContent,
      })
    });
```

I've also tried to return base64 image string like this:

```
    cy.intercept(
      '/uploads/test.png',
      {
        headers: {"Content-Type": "image/jpg"},
        body:
      'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAARCUlEQVR4Xu1deXQURRr...
```

But it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems like a job for a [fixture](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#With-a-fixture)

```js
cy.intercept("/uploads/test.png", { fixture: "logo.png" })
```

By default, you would place your `logo.png` file into the `cypress/fixtures` directory however you can [configure it to use another location](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders-Files)

Comment: I had also to add a `,null` to my fixture:
```cy.intercept('/not-found', {
  fixture: 'media/gif.mp4,null',
})``` as suggested in this section: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#With-a-StaticResponse-object